Django Admin is not Showing
What is the problem below and how to solve it? After runserver I didn't see the admin panel.
Page not found (404)
> “E:\Masud Ahmad\Pyhood\MyBlogs\blogone\admin” does not exist
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
Using the URLconf defined in blogone.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
base/ [name='base']
[name='home']
> ^(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, admin, matched the last one.

I tried to fix it, I checked the code repeatedly, but couldn't point out the problem.
Here my urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('base/', views.BASE, name='base'),
    path('', views.INDEX, name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


Hello Masud, please edit your question to include the contents of your urls.py.

What's the URL you are trying to access? Are you including the trailing slash, as is defined in your urls.py? localhost:8000/admin/ for example

can you share your settings.py file or github link? github would be better one if you are fine to have us to look into your code.

You are missing the trailing slash when hitting your url. You should be accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
